# Rails Postgres config host mistaken as database name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

have been pulling my hair due this issue :

When I run my rails application on my mac it seems the `host` is mistaken as `database name` and it only happens on development environment.

This is my database.yml :

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] || 'admin' %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] || 'password'%>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'localhost'%>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: cid_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: cid_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: cid_api
```

Then when I run :

```
$ bundle exec rake db:create
```

It returns me this :

```
Database 'localhost' already exists
```

anyone has any idea what happen in my local environment ?
FYI, I tried rbenv and rvm both has same issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Rails using `DATABASE_URL` environment variable as a place to put connection string. So when I put database host inside env variable `DATABASE_URL` it will use it as default

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fb764ba63e53b728873075a0d207b993409798a2/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L88-L102

So to fix it what I need is rename `DATABASE_URL` to `DATABASE_HOST` which is the correct one anyway. Thank you